# i want to animate li item like wave form left to right onhover of each li

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

```
    <!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="animation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="svertical">
            <li><a>MenuElement1</a></li>
            <li><a>MenuElement2</a></li>
            <li><a>MenuElement3</a></li>
            <li><a>MenuElement4</a></li>
            <li><a>MenuElement5</a></li>
            <li><a>MenuElement6</a></li>        
        </ul>

    </body>
</html>`
```

`
    CSS to add animation
      css to display the li items form this i created my menu itemsCSS to add animation
      css to display the li items form this i created my menu itemsCSS to add animation
      css to display the li items form this i created my menu items

```
ul.svertical{
width: 200px; /* width of menu */
overflow: auto;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#eeeeee), color-stop(100%,#cccccc)) no-repeat; /* background of menu */
margin:0px;
padding: 0;
padding-top: 7px; /* top padding */
list-style-type: none;
position:absolute;
}

ul.svertical li{
text-align: left; /* right align menu links */
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
text-indent: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
background: rgb(127, 201, 68); /* initial background color of links */
font: bold 16px Germand;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 5px;
color: black;
border:1px solid;
border-radius:5px;
left:-110px;
}

animation.js

$(document).ready( function(){
    var timer = 0;
    $('.svertical li').hover( 
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({ left: "0px" }, 'fast');
        $('.svertical li').each(function (i){
            timer = (timer * .8 + 150);
            $(this).stop().animate({ left: "0px" }, timer);

        });
    },
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({ left: "-110px" }, 'fast');
        $('.svertical li').each(function (i){
            timer = (timer * .8 + 150);
            $(this).stop().animate({ left: "-110px" }, timer);

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: if i hover for the first time it working fine but after that it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Seems you just need to reset your timer variable:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    var timer = 0;
    $('.svertical li').hover( 
    function(){
        timer = 0; // Reset timer variable
        $(this).stop().animate({ left: "0px" }, 'fast');
        $('.svertical li').each(function (i){
            timer = (timer * .8 + 150);
            $(this).stop().animate({ left: "0px" }, timer);

        });
    },
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({ left: "-110px" }, 'fast');
        $('.svertical li').each(function (i){
            timer = (timer * .8 + 150);
            $(this).stop().animate({ left: "-110px" }, timer);

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks it's working fine now but i need animation to start from the li on which i first hover for example if hover 4th li animation should start from 4th li but it is always starting from the first li

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want the "wave" to only animate down? For example, if you hover over MenuElement4 then you expect 4,5, and 6 to "do the wave"?

Comment: animation to be like the video provide in the below link

Comment: http://youtu.be/XB1UA45ZlO8   please help me i tried a lot i am not able to do it i am new to jquery

Comment: I see. That's a little more involved. You'll need to approach it differently. I'm not going to write the code for you, but I'm happy to help with any problems you run into.

Comment: thaks for your comments i will try it